# Как в PyQt5 решить проблему с использованием radioButton

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, сигналы-слоты, qradiobutton

Программа имеет радио кнопки **`RB_1`** и **`RB_2`**. При выборе любой из них можно, используя кнопки **плюс** и **минус**, выводить в **`label_1`** и **`label_2`** число.

Каждое нажатие кнопок **плюс** и **минус** прибавляет или вычитает **единицу**.

Можно заметить, что если несколько раз просто переключиться между радио кнопками, то счет меняется не на единицу, а больше. Т.е. радио кнопки вмешиваются в счет, чего быть не должно. И радио кнопка **`NONE`** тоже ведет себя не нормально. Что надо исправить, чтобы решить проблему?

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("clickB_save.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('New')
        self.EXIT.clicked.connect(self.exit_action)

        self.RB_1.clicked.connect(self.vetka_1)
        self.RB_2.clicked.connect(self.vetka_2)


        self.spinBox_1.setRange(0, 100)
        self.spinBox_1.setValue(50)
        self.counter_1 = 0
        self.spinBox_2.setRange(0, 100)
        self.spinBox_2.setValue(50)
        self.counter_2 = 0

        self.load_settings()

    def clickme_ON(self):
        self.CLICK_ME_1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.plus_Clicked())
        self.CLICK_ME_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.minus_Clicked())

    def plus_Clicked(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.counter_1 += 1
            self.label_1.setText(str(self.counter_1))
            print(f'плюс 1 слева:', self.counter_1)
        elif self.index == 2:
            self.counter_2 += 1
            self.label_2.setText(str(self.counter_2))
            print(f'плюс 1 справа:', self.counter_2)

    def minus_Clicked(self):
        if self.index == 1:
            self.counter_1 -= 1
            self.label_1.setText(str(self.counter_1))
            print(f'минус 1 слева:', self.counter_1)
        elif self.index == 2:
            self.counter_2 -= 1
            self.label_2.setText(str(self.counter_2))
            print(f'минус 1 справа:', self.counter_2)

    def vetka_1(self):
        self.index = 1
        self.clickme_ON()
        print('vetka_1')

    def vetka_2(self):
        self.index = 2
        self.clickme_ON()
        print('vetka_2')


    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue', self.spinBox_1.value())
        settings.setValue('Counter', self.counter_1)
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue_2', self.spinBox_2.value())
        settings.setValue('Counter_2', self.counter_2)

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.spinBox_1.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue', self.spinBox_1.value())))
        self.counter_1 = int(settings.value('Counter', self.counter_1))
        self.spinBox_2.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue_2', self.spinBox_2.value())))
        self.counter_2 = int(settings.value('Counter_2', self.counter_2))


    def exit_action(self):
        self.save_settings()
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***clickB_save.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Deqart</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="CLICK_ME_1">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>250</x>
      <y>80</y>
      <width>125</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>MS Shell Dlg 2</family>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <italic>false</italic>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>+</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_1">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>180</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox_1">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>420</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="EXIT">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>530</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>93</width>
      <height>28</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Выход</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinBox_2">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>510</x>
      <y>420</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>51</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="CLICK_ME_2">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>250</x>
      <y>180</y>
      <width>125</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>MS Shell Dlg 2</family>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <italic>false</italic>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>-</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>320</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>50</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>14</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>140</x>
      <y>290</y>
      <width>351</width>
      <height>80</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="RB_1">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>20</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>RB 1</string>
     </property>
     <property name="checkable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="checked">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="RB_2">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>130</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>RB 2</string>
     </property>
     <property name="checkable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="checked">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="RB_3">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>250</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <pointsize>12</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>NONE</string>
     </property>
     <property name="checkable">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="checked">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <action name="action">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Выход</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Настройки</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="action_4">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Диалоговое окно</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я упорядочил ваш код и прокомментировал.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings


CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'

class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()

        loadUi("clickB_save.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle('New')
        self.EXIT.clicked.connect(self.exit_action)

# ?        self.RB_1.clicked.connect(self.vetka_1)
# ?        self.RB_2.clicked.connect(self.vetka_2)
# ?        self.index = 0

        self.spinBox_1.setRange(0, 100)
        self.spinBox_1.setValue(50)
        self.counter_1 = 0
        self.spinBox_2.setRange(0, 100)
        self.spinBox_2.setValue(50)
        self.counter_2 = 0

        self.load_settings()
        
        self.label_1.setNum(self.counter_1)                  # +++
        self.label_2.setNum(self.counter_2)                  # +++

# ?    def clickme_ON(self): 
# Неправильно вставлять в метод, который вызывается многократно 
        self.CLICK_ME_1.clicked.connect(self.plus_Clicked)
        self.CLICK_ME_2.clicked.connect(self.minus_Clicked)

    def plus_Clicked(self):
#        if self.index == 1:
        if self.RB_1.isChecked():                            # +++
            self.counter_1 += 1
            self.label_1.setText(str(self.counter_1))
            print(f'плюс 1 слева:', self.counter_1)
        elif self.RB_2.isChecked():                          #self.index == 2:
            self.counter_2 += 1
            self.label_2.setText(str(self.counter_2))
            print(f'плюс 1 справа:', self.counter_2)

    def minus_Clicked(self):
        if self.RB_1.isChecked():
            self.counter_1 -= 1
            self.label_1.setText(str(self.counter_1))
            print(f'минус 1 слева:', self.counter_1)
        elif self.RB_2.isChecked():
            self.counter_2 -= 1
            self.label_2.setText(str(self.counter_2))
            print(f'минус 1 справа:', self.counter_2)

    '''
    def vetka_1(self):
        self.index = 1
# ?        self.clickme_ON()
        print('vetka_1')

    def vetka_2(self):
        self.index = 2
# ?        self.clickme_ON()
        print('vetka_2')
    '''

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue', self.spinBox_1.value())
        settings.setValue('Counter', self.counter_1)
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue_2', self.spinBox_2.value())
        settings.setValue('Counter_2', self.counter_2)

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.spinBox_1.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue', self.spinBox_1.value())))
        self.counter_1 = int(settings.value('Counter', self.counter_1))
        self.spinBox_2.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue_2', self.spinBox_2.value())))
        self.counter_2 = int(settings.value('Counter_2', self.counter_2))

    def exit_action(self, e):
        self.save_settings()
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]